# How to get data from two telerik grid view in two separate forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am trying to get data from two different and separate telerik Gridview. (first one is for Customers and second one for editing selected customer)

I want to get from first customer Id. I made an object from  previous form and tried to make it work but when it wants to get the first element of the last form it's always 0.

Visual Studio tells me this with a run time error

Here are my codes in 3 different layer

first one

```
       private void btnEdt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ref_View_Model = new View_model._View_Model();
        Ref_C = new Customers();

        foreach (var RowInfo in Ref_C.radGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            FireCell = RowInfo.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }


        Ref_C.radGridView1.CurrentRow.Delete();
        Ref_C.customersTableAdapter.Update(Ref_C.sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet);
        Ref_C.customersTableAdapter.Fill(Ref_C.sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet.Customers);

        Ref_View_Model.GetEditCustomers(FireCell, txtFName.Text, txtLName.Text, txtPhn.Text, txtDdrss.Text);
```

second layer

```
        public void GetEditCustomers(string _id,string _fName, string _lName, string _phone, string _address)
    {
        Ref_Model = new Model._Model();
        Ref_Model.EditCustomres(_id, _fName, _lName, _phone, _address);
    }
```

and the third one

```
        public void EditCustomres( string _id,string _fName, string _lName, string _phone, string _address)
    {

        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=" + "Sales and Inventory System" + ";Integrated Security=True;";
        Con = new SqlConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = Connection_String;
        Helper = Convert.ToInt32(_id);
        Con.Open();
        Cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Cmd.Connection = Con;
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Cmd.CommandText = "update Customers "+
                            "set FName=" + _fName + ",LName=" + _lName + ",Phone=" + _phone + ",[Address]=" + _address + 
                              "where Id like " + Helper;
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

I dont know how to reach to the line in side the loop i tried linq but it didn't worked well

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a cleaner way, get the **object** from the row and get the value that you need. Personally I don't recommend try to getting the values using the cell index, **only if is absolutely necessary** because sometimes you are just guessing what the cell contains.

As I don't know what kind of objects you are displaying, just change the **MyObject** in this code. *(I'm just supposing that grid contains customers)*

**myValue** is the value that you are looking for.

```
foreach (var RowInfo in Ref_C.radGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    var customer = RowInfo.DataBoundItem as MyObject;

    // Reach the property that are located in Cells[0]
    var myValue = customer.SomeProperty
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm using telerik grid view and I want it's first value which is Id,       What should i write instead of myobject??

Comment: exactly what should i put instead of (someproperty),cuase after dot(.) nothing comes

Comment: Yeah nothing comes because you need to replace **MyObject** for the object that you are using to fill the grid, not sure if **Customer** is the type that you are using. Maybe if you show me how are you filling the grid I can help you with that, or try var type = RowInfo.DataBoundItem.GetType(); and debug to check what type is the object that the Row contain

Comment: i'm using another form for filling a telerik grid view (Which is a customer's information ) after saving the form it's information goes to DB and in the grid view (Which is another form)

Comment: Try FireCell = RowInfo.Cells[0].Text.ToString();

Comment: after Cell and pressing dot (.) there is no text

Comment: Is FireCell a string?

Comment: Cell has a Value, not Text. Use Value and cast it if needed.